# Late binding object to existing instance via handle in VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, late-binding

**This question pertains to VBA Internet Explorer automation**

What I have is an Internet Explorer window that loads a dialog box with buttons when the page loads.

**Here are the givens:**

1. The dialog box is of the **"Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame"** class
2. It isn't considered an app window like its originating IE window.
3. Its "form" and button "ID's are obtainable but not within DOM of the originating IE document
4. So, referencing said IDs to interact with them does not work.
5. Similarly, injecting JavaScript attached to its buttons does not work
6. The dialog box can't be bypassed by closing it. A "continue" button must be pressed.

**So I figured I'd use another method:**

If I cycle through all windows, I can obtain the dialog box's window handle via its window title.

**With that said, is there a way to late-bind "Object A" to the dialog box's window via handle?**

**And if so, is it then possible to late-bind "Object B" to "Object A's" document/form in order to interact with it?**

This would be like accessing an existing instance of an open Excel workbook and late binding an object to it in order to interact with the workbook itself.

**Note:** I have used Selenium in the past, and while it may be a better solution to get around this dialog box, translating the rest of my (already) written program into Java would be a nightmare.

**Note2:** Using winHttp or other "headless" methods isn't an option

**Any help is appreciated! Thanks!**

Comment: * late-bind "Object A" to the dialog box's window via handle* only if the window supports it. Only Richedit windows support it to my knowledge. Does Explorer's ShellWindows find it. `Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")` and `Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows` and `For Each window in AllWindows` and `msgbox  window.locationname` and `next`.

Comment: This was the first method I tried. However I found an example which does locate the dialog popup: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=52 . But I am still stuck on how I'd late bind using this example

Comment: That code has nothing to do with late binding or even COM. It is Windows API interface to windows on Windows. It also uses an old non recommended way to find windows that only finds the first window (ie `FindWindow()` rather than `EnumWindows`). If your buttons are *button windows* (`FindWindowsEx()` will find them) then you can send a Click message to them via a Windows message using the `SendMessage()` API call.

Comment: I have some sample code embedded in another program that lists all windows on a system. It gives output like this `Order Level WindowText ClassName HWnd ParentHWnd ProcessID ParentProcessID ThreadID ModuleNameHWin EXENameProcess
` and `198 0 Newest 'batch-file or vbscript or cmd' Questions - Stack Overflow - Internet Explorer TabThumbnailWindow 6292800 6423328 5432 6488 6820 «Not Available Error=126» iexplore.exe
`

Comment: Do you have example that uses findwindowsEx()/SendMessage() or one that simply closes the dialog window using findWindowsEx()?

If I can close it, I can inject some javascript which will accomplish what I want without using SendMessage() to click a button

Comment: Can't reproduce to attempt solution but you are aware of selenium basic as a wrapper for vba?

Comment: Had a similar problem - my solution is here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318737/automating-the-html-document-in-an-ie-web-dialog-window/54318776#54318776