# Get href from Pop up Windows using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I browse  one private site with with user name password using VBA and Filters Data,

Each row of Filter data have hyperlink and that hyperlink takes me to new popup window.

In New popup window there is href like

```
href="/ENIT/imsscsv_download.jsp?filename=07730_Dormant_Account_07022019.csv&filepath=/dmsapp/mnt/appln/DMSWeblogic/ENIT_FILES/COMMUNICATION_LOG/SENDER/INVESTIGATION_ALERTS/07730_Dormant_Account_07022019.csv"
```

how to extract that href value from popup window

HTML Codes of Popup Window

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Communication Log</title>
    <LINK REL ="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" 
HREF="../css/ENIT_Table_Style.css" TITLE="Style">
    <script type= "" language="javascript" src="../js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="" language="javascript" src="/ENIT/js/tablesort.js"></script>
   <script>
        var sentDate ='08-Feb-2019';  
        //sentDate = '01/29/2016';
        var dt  = sentDate.split(/\-|\s/)   //Added By Mohsin on 14-Mar-2016 for Transactional Alert
        sentDateFormatted = new Date(dt.reverse().join('/'));

        function getMemberList()
        {
            var callbackFunction = populateMemberList;
            var CMSegment = 'N';
            var FNOSegment = 'N';
            var CDSSegment = 'N';
            var IPOSegment = 'N';
            var segmentList = "";
            var isInHouseMemberList = "N";
            if(document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_CM") != null && document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_CM").checked)
            {
                CMSegment = 'Y';
                segmentList += "CM|";
            }
            if(document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_FNO") != null && document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_FNO").checked)
            {
                FNOSegment = 'Y';
                segmentList += "FNO|";
            }
            if(document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_CDS") != null && document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_CDS").checked)
            {
                CDSSegment = 'Y';
                segmentList += "CDS|"; //Due to URL redirect problem '%CDS%' treat as '=S%'
            }
            if(document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_IPO") != null && document.getElementById("rdBtnSegment_IPO").checked)
            {
                IPOSegment = 'Y';
                segmentList += "IPO|";
            }

            if(document.getElementById("selectAll") != null && document.getElementById("selectAll").checked)
            {
               isInHouseMemberList = "N";
            }

            if(document.getElementById("InHouseMember") != null && document.getElementById("InHouseMember").checked)
            {
               isInHouseMemberList = "Y";
            }
            //alert(segmentList.substring(0,segmentList.length-1))
            var urlParams = "?segmentList="+ segmentList.substring(0,segmentList.length-1) +"&isInHouseMemberList="+ isInHouseMemberList+"&CMSegment="+CMSegment+"&FNOSegment="+FNOSegment+"&CDSSegment="+CDSSegment+"&IPOSegment="+IPOSegment; 
            var jspWithParams = "getMemberList_XMLHTTP.jsp"+ urlParams;
           // window.open(jspWithParams);
            submitAsynchronously(segmentList, callbackFunction, jspWithParams);
        }

        function populateMemberList()
        {
            var slctMemberList = document.getElementById("memberList");
            if (req.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (req.status == 200)
                {
                    var NeatIdOptionElements = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("MemberOption");
//                    alert(responseXML)
                    clearDropDownBox(slctMemberList);
                    //alert(NeatIdOptionElements.length)
                    for (i = 0; i < NeatIdOptionElements.length; i++)
                    {
                        LOVOptionObj = NeatIdOptionElements[i];
                        LOVOptionTxt = LOVOptionObj.getAttribute("meaning").substring(0,60);
                        LOVOptionValue = LOVOptionObj.getAttribute("value");
                        slctMemberList.options[i + 1] = new Option(LOVOptionTxt, LOVOptionValue);

                        if(!document.getElementById("ExcelId").checked)
                            slctMemberList.options[i+1].selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

       function uploadExcel()
       {
           window.open("uploadMemberList.jsp","ExcelUpload",'resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=yes,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,height=200,width=500,top=100,left=250');           
       }

       //Start: 45 Days Restriction to the reply of the Transactional Alert

        function validateDays()
        {
            var days = 45*(24*60*60*1000);
            var newDate  =(new Date(new Date() - days));
            //alert(newDate);
            //alert(sentDateFormatted);
            if (newDate > sentDateFormatted){
                alert("Reply can only be submitted within 45 days of receiving alert");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
               return (validateAdminCommunicationLog());
            }
        }

      //End: 45 Days Restriction to the reply of the Transactional Alert

   </script>
  </head>

<body class="mainBody" >
  <script language="javascript" src="/ENIT/js/communicationLog.js"></script>

   <script>
       function printDocument()
        {
                document.all.MainTableDiv.style.overflow = "visible";
                window.print();            
        }

   </script>
<form name="communicationLogForm" id="communicationLogForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="communicationLogFileReceiverAdminToMember.jsp" onsubmit="return validateDays();">

<input type="hidden" name="accessType" id="accessType" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="logInAs" id="logInAs" value="Member"/>
<input type="hidden" name="replyBy" id="replyBy" value="346"/>
<input type="hidden" name="memId" id="memId" value="346"/>
<!-- Mem Name & mem Code-  Added By Smita on 26 Mar 2013 for Investigation Alerts -->
<input type="hidden" name="memName" id="memName" value="ICICI SECURITIES LIMITED"/>
<input type="hidden" name="memCode" id="memCode" value="07730"/>
<input type="hidden" name="reqRefNo" id="reqRefNo" value="EXCHANGE/COMM_LOG/105966"/>

<h4>* Please note that reply for an alert can be submitted only within the 45 days of receiving alert</h4>

<input type="hidden" name="dept" id="dept" value="Investigation"/>
<Div align="center" class="topDiv">

    <table>
            <tr>

                <td class="pageHeadingTd" align="right">
                <b>Transactional Alert</b>
                </td>                                                     

            <td class="noBorderTD" align="right" width="60%">

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
    <DIV class="mainTableDivStyle" id="MainTableDiv">
      <div id="processBar" style="display:none" align="center" class="bottomDiv"><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <img src="../images/progress_bar.gif" border="0"><font color="blue"><b>Processing.....Please Wait.</b></font>
     </div> 
     <table id="mainTable" border=1 class="mainTableStyle">


         <tr>
                     <td width="30%">
                        <b> Subject : </b>
                     </td>
                     <td width="70%">

                      <input type="hidden" name="subject" id="subject" size="60" maxlength="100" value="Dormant Account"/>
                      Dormant Account

                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td width="30%">
                        <b> Text Message: </b>
                     </td>
                     <td width="70%">

                      <textarea rows="7" cols="100" name="textMessage" id="textMessage" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>

                     </td>
                 </tr>

                      <td>
                        <b> File Attached : </b>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <a href="/ENIT/imsscsv_download.jsp?filename=07730_Dormant_Account_07022019.csv&filepath=/dmsapp/mnt/appln/DMSWeblogic/ENIT_FILES/COMMUNICATION_LOG/SENDER/INVESTIGATION_ALERTS/07730_Dormant_Account_07022019.csv">
                     07730_Dormant_Account_07022019.csv</a>
                     </td>


         <!--Code to get List of Member's reply-->

         <tr >
             <td><b>Member Code :</b></td><td> 07730</td> 
             </tr>
          <tr>   
                <td><b>Member Name :</b></td><td>ABC LIMITED</td>
              </tr>

          <tr> 
          <td><b>Reply:</b>
          </td>
          <td>
                   <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="replyTextMessage" id="replyTextMessage"></textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                 <td><b>File To be Attached : </b></td>
                 <td>
                     <input type="file" size="40" id="ReplyFile1" name="ReplyFile1" onkeyup="this.blur()" onkeydown="this.blur()" /> <b>Reply File 1</b><br>
                     <input type="file" size="40" id="ReplyFile2" name="ReplyFile2" onkeyup="this.blur()" onkeydown="this.blur()" /> <b>Reply File 2</b><br>
                     <input type="file" size="40" id="ReplyFile2" name="ReplyFile3" onkeyup="this.blur()" onkeydown="this.blur()" /> <b>Reply File 3</b>
                 </td>
         </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="noBorderTD" colspan="8">
                    <b>* Note: </b>Please ensure the size of the attachment is less  than 5 MB.
                </td>
            </tr>

      </table>

    <DIV class="bottomDiv" align="center">

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </div>
</div>

</form>

<script>    
     function getMemberListFromSession()
     {
         var memberListCmb = document.getElementById("memberList");        
     }       
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

One secured site showing alert of transaction. Each Alert gives log file, Each Alert row has hyperlink and that hyperlink navigates to popup window

```
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.internetexplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate NSELINK
ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop


Set HTMLDoc = IE.document


HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_id").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_id").Value = (NSEUSR)
HTMLDoc.getElementById("member_code").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("member_code").Value = "07730"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("password").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("password").Value = (NSEPWD)


Dim VAL As String
VAL = InputBox("Enter Captcha Value", "CAPTCHA", "")
If VAL = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginCap").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("loginCap").Value = (VAL)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("user_id").Focus
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ext-gen39").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ext-gen39").Click

While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("btn_Skip").Click
While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ext-gen20").Focus
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ext-gen20").Click
While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
HTMLDoc.querySelector("[tabindex='1']").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

IE.navigate NSELINK2
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("communicationLogFilterFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("communicationType").Value = "EXCHANGE_TO_MEMBER"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("communicationLogFilterFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("txtFromDate").Value = (LD)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("communicationLogFilterFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("txtToDate").Value = (LD)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
HTMLDoc.getElementById("communicationLogFilterFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("search").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
```

Required Href value in popup window

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you have that window handle. If you do then it is simply:

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[href]").href
```

If not, check whether this `href` value is present elsewhere in the pre-popup window. Otherwise, you will need to loop and find this window first. You might be able to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318776/6241235) for example.