# Accessing Web page dialog box with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a web data scraping macro from within excel and managed to get through automating the login and a navigate a few links.  The final stage opens the info I need in a Web page dialog box, which makes the originating page inaccessible and pauses my macro.  I am also not able to view the HTML behind this dialog.

How do I access this web page dialog? I need to either be able to read the table it displays or automate clicking one of the buttons.  This button opens the info I need on the original page.

EDIT

[image]

This is the code of the function that is called from the onclick event of the rows in the table of the parent window:

```
function displayReport(guid, index)
        {
            var url;
            //aParams added to match layout for other minireport calls
            var aParams = new Array(2);
            aParams[0] = index;
            if(guid.length == 0)
            {
                // Show normal local mini-report
                url = "../reporting/minireportframe.aspx?report_index=" + index + "&ID=ACBD6E945ACA4509A9A0E2E701EFA8E7&file=yes&hide=yes&hide_fullreport_button=true";
            }
            else
            {
                // Show OpenNet report via web service
                var windowWidth = 500;
                var windowHeight = 525;
                url = "report_viewer.aspx?guid=" + guid + "&index=" + index + "&ID=ACBD6E945ACA4509A9A0E2E701EFA8E7";
            }
               var dialogFeatures =
                    "dialogWidth:" + windowWidth + "px; " +
                    "dialogHeight:" + windowHeight + "px; " +
                    "status: no; help: no; center: yes; resizable: yes;";

                var success =  window.showModalDialog(
                    url,
                    aParams,
                    dialogFeatures
                );
            if(aParams[1] == "SHOWREPORT"){
                document.getElementById("hidReportIndex").value = aParams[0];
                document.getElementById("hidAction").value = aParams[1];
                document.getElementById("PatientReportsForm").submit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to offer suggestions with no real details about exactly what kind of "dialog" it is you're dealing with.

Comment: Hi Tim. Not sure how else to describe it.  Afraid I can't post a screenshot as it is sensitive work-related data.  The dialog box is in the form of a webpage which opens in a separate smaller window.  It has tables of data (the data I am trying to extract) and buttons.  The parent window is unclickable while this dialog window is open and the macro I have written that works with the objects on the parent window stops at the point the dialog window opens.

Comment: Is is a new browser window, or a modal window created using script/css?  You can take a screenshot and then obscure/remove anything sensitive

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Just added a screenshot of the dialog box and parent window and the code that gets me to this point.

Comment: Might be worth adding either the code behind the webpage or, if sensetive, obfuscate anything sensetive out of it. That way we can see *how* the 'dialog box' is created.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318737/automating-the-html-document-in-an-ie-web-dialog-window