# Trying to automate the manual entry/process in Internet Explorer webpage using VBA, but stuck with a window popup value entry

Tags: html, vba

Automating the manual process in Internet explorer webpage using VBA.
When clicking on a text box in a page, it displays a seperate Window Popup.

There is a text field in the window popup, where i have to enter a value, but no HTML code is associated to that popup(as i dont see Inspect element to get the HTML code).

So how do i get to the textbox in the window dialog box that pops up and enter the value?? when there is no "inspect element" is available.

Note: Webpage is access restricted,so cant share the link.

Any help would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kttrw.png)
[VBScript Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HctyH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: from the screenshot that's not a javascript `prompt` input, so you can try something like the approach here: [Automating the HTML document in an IE web dialog window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318737/automating-the-html-document-in-an-ie-web-dialog-window)

Or try overwriting the `showModalDialog` function:

```vb
idoc.parentWindow.execScript _
           "window.showModalDialog = function(){return '09876';};", "JScript"
```

---

That sounds like javascript `window.prompt()` so you could try replacing that function in the page with a function that returns the value you'd want entered in the prompt when it pops up.

```vb
Set elements = idoc.getElementsByName("userBSB") 

For Each oHTML_Element In idoc.getElementsByTagName("input") 
    If oHTML_Element.Name = "userBSB" Then 

       'override the window.prompt function
       idoc.parentWindow.execScript _
           "window.prompt = function(){return '09876';};", "JScript"  

       oHTML_Element.Click
       Exit For 
    End If
Next 

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Loop 

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
```

Comment: Hey Tim,below is the code i am working on
Set elements = idoc.getElementsByName("userBSB")
         For Each oHTML_Element In idoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If oHTML_Element.Name = "userBSB" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
        Next
        
        Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
        'i have to enter a number(09876) in the textbox of the windows dialog box, no HTML code been associated with this window.how do i go to the textbox of the window dialog box"

Comment: Tim,i have tried the above code,but it didnt work. Actually the dialog box pops up after the  click(oHTML_Element.Click).So i have tried the below too,no luck
For Each oHTML_Element In idoc.getElementsByTagName("input") 
    If oHTML_Element.Name = "userBSB" Then 

       'override the window.prompt function
              oHTML_Element.Click
       Exit For 
    End If
Next 
Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Loop 
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
idoc.parentWindow.execScript "window.prompt = function(){return '09876';};", "JScript"

Comment: *If* whatever is popping up for you to enter a value is a `window.prompt` dialog, then you have to override that function *before* you click the element.  I made a small edit above to remove a line continuation which I'd added in the wrong place.  Can you try the edited code?  If that doesn't work, then a screenshot of the pop-up would help.

Comment: i have tried the edited code,it didnt work.i have added the image now of the popup(have to enter value in the textbox).Thanks again for your help Tim.

Comment: OK that's not a `window.prompt`, so any answer will be more complex.  Try (eg) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318737/automating-the-html-document-in-an-ie-web-dialog-window

Comment: I have tried with the WIndows API methid you mentioned, still the code stops when the webpage Dialog pops up. 
I have tried with the VBscript, where  i am successful to click on OK in the dialogbox, by calling the script in my VBA code. 
But i am not sure how to enter a value in the text box of the dialog window.I have attached the script written which will call the dialog popup and clicks OK. 
Is there anyway you can help on VBscript or by anyother method?

Comment: I think one approach is to try to find the script which opens the dialog, and overwrite that part of the code with a function which just returns the value you want.   Without access to the page it's difficult to be more specific than that though.