# How to interact with IE script prompt VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I click a button on a webpage automatically and it pulls up a popup "window" in the top left hand side of the Internet Explorer that looks as such

[image]

The issue is I cannot seem to run any code while this is active, I have tried to merely SendKeys "enter" at it but the code only executes after the window disappears. How do I execute code on it when it appears to pause my runtime?

---

Added image reference for location of "window.prompt" function.

[image: window.prompt location]

How would I edit the variable "t" in this instance from VBA? I mean to set it to return null to skip over it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594408/trying-to-automate-the-manual-entry-process-in-internet-explorer-webpage-using-v/66594713#66594713

Comment: Does clicking the button only show this prompt or perform other operations in the background too? As an alternative, you can try to use XML HTTP requests. Further, you can also try to use any UI Automation library to click the `OK` button on the prompt. If possible then could you please try to provide more information about the issue may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It only brings up that prompt but once the prompt is completed, it downloads the file. I am going to try multiple things today so I will get back to you

Comment: @TimWilliams for altering window.prompt, I found the function but it is saved as a variable in the JScript file. Image reference added to post. Is there any way I can edit a JS variable from inside VBA?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you replace `window.prompt` before triggering the script you posted, it should be fine:

```vb
   iedoc.parentWindow.execScript _
           "window.prompt = function(){return 'whatever.csv';};", "JScript"
```

Where `iedoc` is your document object.